# How to setup JUnit testing framework in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit

I started reading a book Test-Driven Development By Example written by Kent Beck. The examples he provides there are in Java and he uses JUnit testing framework. I decided to go with the book and repeat after Kent to learn TDD better.

So I installed IntelliJ Idea and created empty project for the first example:
[image]

Then I went to google on how to setup JUnit and got stuck. In the
[Prepare For Testing](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/testing.html#ij-add-library) article in the Manually add a testing
library section they tell me:

> Follow these steps to add a library if you're building your project
> with the native IntelliJ IDEA builder:
>
> From the main menu, select File | Project Structure (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S)
> or click the Project Structure button on the toolbar.
>
> Under Project Settings, select Libraries and click the New Project
> Library + button | From Maven.
>
> In the dialog that opens, specify the necessary library artifact, for
> example: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2 or
> org.testng:testng:6.14.3.
>
> Apply the changes and close the dialog.
> [image]

I get stuck at the "Under Project Settings, select Libraries and click the New Project Library + button | From Maven". I don't have any Maven buttons. When I press on the + button, it opens local explorer:
[image]

Couldn't find anything in google about this issue, everyone's just suggesting "Just install JUnit from Maven".

So how to setup JUnit in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I created empty project and it wasn't a Java project. After I downloaded and installed JDK:
[image]

And then created Java project with this JDK, Maven shows up when I press on the plus button:
[image]

I managed to install JUnit.